# Who named the chatbot "Does Elisha speak?"

Tags: discussion

Who named the chatbot "Does Elisha speak?"

I have to admit - The first time I saw it, I thought it was a human, and I thought it was a question.

Also - Does the phrase "Does Elisha speak?" have Biblical significance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did. (With some [suggestions from bruised reed](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/who-named-the-chatbot-does-elisha-speak#comment8254_3814).)

All of the "Elisha" accounts are chat bots that post the output of RSS feeds from various sites. There is a collection of them:

## Elisha spake thus:

- [Eschewmenical](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/) - The Christianity Stack Exchange Blog

## Does Elisha Speak?

- [Meta Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/) - Recent questions

## Ask Elisha

[History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/)

- Newest questions tagged [christianity](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity?sort=newest)
- Newest questions tagged [church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church?sort=newest)
- Newest questions tagged [protestant-church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protestant-church?sort=newest)
- Newest questions tagged [catholic-church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic-church?sort=newest)
- Newest questions tagged [jesus](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jesus?sort=newest)
- Newest questions tagged [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades?sort=newest)
- Newest questions tagged [bible](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible?sort=newest)
- Newest questions tagged [reformation](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformation?sort=newest)

## Was there ever an Elisha?

[Skeptics Stack Exchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)

- Active questions tagged [christianity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity?sort=active)
- Active questions tagged [jesus-christ](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jesus-christ?sort=newest)
- Active questions tagged [bible](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible?sort=newest)

## You did what to the cows Elisha?!

- [Hinduism Stack Exchange](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) - Active questions tagged [christianity](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity?sort=newest)

## Enlightened Elisha

- [Buddhism Stack Exchange](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/) - Active questions tagged [christianity](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity?sort=newest)

## The Prophet Elisha

- [Islam Stack Exchange](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) - Active questions tagged [christianity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity?sort=newest)

## Elisha and his Brethren

- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) (Judaism Stack Exchange) - Active questions tagged [christianity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity?sort=newest)

## Elisha Ponders...

- [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) - Active questions tagged [christianity](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity?sort=newest)

As the chat room is mostly configured for the benefit of those that hang around there a lot and is not necessarily any body's introduction to the network I think it is reasonable to assume people will figure out what is going on. The "Elisha" theme was just an attempt at humor and livening up an otherwise boring bot. And yes, it has Biblical significance. You should read up on A) who he was and B) how his figure is referenced in the New Testament.

As you can see the newest couple of feed additions don't have names yet. Suggestions accepted.

Comment: For Hinduism "Elisha and Brahma are best friends."

Comment: For Buddhism "Elisha is in Nirvana."

Comment: I had never thought of how Elisha's ministry has some elements [corresponding](http://www.heartquest101.com/2010/11/18/elisha-in-the-new-testament/comment-page-1/) to Jesus' ministry.

Comment: For mi yodeya I suggest some variation on "shabbot shalom," because it has bot in the name when spelled this way. Maybe "Shabbot Shalom Elisha."

Comment: Buddhism: "Enlightened Elisha"; Islam: "The Prophet Elisha"; Mi Yodeya: "Elisha and his Brethren"; Hinduism: "You did what to the cows Elisha??"

Comment: @bruisedreed. I am impressed.

Comment: @bruisedreed Those are awesome. I've been hoping for something that had a content tie-in and might be amusing without being offensive or seen as irreverent to Christians or as ridicule by the other sites. I think those work, I'll rename the bots now!

Comment: You missed a perfect opportunity to use an interobang. (If you prefer two separate symbols, the exclamation mark should follow the question mark.)

Comment: How about for the History feed - "Elisha of old"?

Comment: Would it be possible to have a bot that checks for when users of this site (with, say, 1000 rep or more) post on another religious SE site?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude Not out of the box no. Somebody with clever programming skills could probably clobber such a bot together using the various SE API's and run it on their own (various community built bots do exist), but I'm aware of nothing even close to this right now.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Could you add the church, protestant-church, catholic-church, jesus, crusades, and bible tags to the ones that Ask Elisha (History) recognizes?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude [Done](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19455042#19455042).

Comment: Thanks. What do you think of these Philosophy.SE tags: faith, philosophy-of-religion, theology, aquinas?