# Chatbot suggestion

Tags: discussion

I suggested this in [a comment](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/who-named-the-chatbot-does-elisha-speak#comment11789_3814) to Caleb a couple days ago. The idea is, in the style of the various Elisha chatbots, to post questions from other SE sites in the Upper Room. If an active user of Christianity.SE (say, 1000 rep or more) posts a question on another religious SE site (Buddhism, Hinduism, Islam, Mi Yodeya), it would post in our chat. Caleb replied to my suggestion thus:

> Somebody with clever programming skills could probably clobber such a
>   bot together using the various SE API's and run it on their own
>   (various community built bots do exist), but I'm aware of nothing even
>   close to this right now.

The questions to discuss, then, are:

1. Would it be worth it?
2. Can someone do it?
3. What criteria would it have for recognizing active members of our community? I mentioned 1000+ rep. Is there a better way?
4. What it be called? Something Elisha-related? Or maybe King Ahab.

Comment: Who will decide which "other religious SE"s will be part of the bot?  Who will maintain it?  For example, while it is not a religion, it is religious, would [LINK](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74887/freemasonry) be counted?  What about Atheism, Islam, etc?  Sounds like a whole lot of work and only a few people will actually care to utilize it.

Comment: @TheFreemason Freemasonry is not considered a religion, Islam is not at all a borderline case and is definitely a religion, atheism seems like it would be useful to include. As far as "who will decide" it's not like it'd be that controversial. Whoever makes it will probably maintain it.

Comment: So, then you are offering to maintain it or are you proposing, "I have a good idea for you to do"?  It never seems like a big deal for those who do not have to actually do the work :D

Comment: @TheFreemason It's a suggestion. You seem to think it's awful to suggest something without offering to do something about it myself, but if I had the expertise then I would. I'm not making a demand on anyone. If someone thinks it's a good idea and volunteers (voluntarily, with zero compulsion) then that's great. If not, fine.

Comment: I am in no way attempting to belittle your suggestion.  I actually find it interesting and would like to see it as well.  The hard part is finding the volunteer, my God bless their soul for their willingness to do work for free.  I am just trying to discover the practicality of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have answers for a few of your questions.

1. **Would it be worth it?**
   Well, it would be fun at first. Until one of the C.SE users starts posting extensively on one of those sites. Then the chat would be inundated with letterboxed messages of posts of that user on a site not related to Christianity. I can see someone saying "Oh, come on, another *fredsbend* post on Judaism.se." So I say give it a go, assuming someone we know can and is willing to build it.
2. **Can someone do it?**
   It ain't me.
3. **What criteria would it have for recognizing active members of our
   community? I mentioned 1000+ rep. Is there a better way?**
   There's currently criteria for being an active member to acquire the yearling badge. It's pretty weak though. I suggest it is definitely higher than that. I suggest there is a call on the last time they were on the site in addition to having a minimum rep count. 1000+ sounds fine to me and has visited the site in the last two weeks. This could lead into a situation similar to what I talked about in question one. Say someone is particularly active on another SE. Then they come over to C.SE really quick, post some good answers and accrue 1000 rep in a short period (if I recall I did it in under a month). Then they loose interest and head back to the other SE. Now we get a feed of their posts in the chatroom when they are not really an active user. But I'm not sure that is really a problem though if it's only two weeks.
4. **What should it be called? Something Elisha-related? Or maybe King Ahab.**
   Not sure. How about "Elisha sent me."